# How to use Select2 tags with newline character tokenSeparator?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I'm creating a select2 input that allows users to paste in csv data and converts it to tags.  My problem is that I'd like to be able to create tags with data that is copied vertically and because select2 uses an `<input type="text" />` element which converts newline characters to a space I am not sure if it is possible.  I'd like to continue to use select2 for this but i'm open to alternatives if there is absolutely no way.

Select2 Definition:

```
$('#search_tags').select2({
    tags: [],
    tokenSeparators: [",", "\t", "\n"],
    dropdownCssClass: 'select2-hidden',
    placeholder: "Paste Here",
    formatNoMatches: function() {return '';}
});
```

HTML:

`<input id="search_tags" type="hidden" style="width:100%;" tabindex="-1">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as you suggest, that the pasted newlines have already been replaced by the time the select2 code starts forming the tags. That's why a custom [tokenizer function](http://select2.github.io/select2/#doc-tokenizer) won't help us here either.

The trick therefore is **to catch the newlines during the paste** and replace them by one of the other separators. Make sure this is executed AFTER your `.select2(...)` code:

```
$('.select2-input').on('paste', function(e) {
    //get the raw pasted text
    var data = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    //replace newlines by tabs and add to conent
    $(this).val($(this).val() + '\t' + data.replace(/\n/g, '\t') + '\t');
    //prevent normal paste behaviour
    return false;
});
```

You can try it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GertG/99t5d5vf/).

**Note:** I'm not quite sure how universal support for `e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text')` is in modern browsers. I've seen suggestions that IE9 requires `window.clipboardData.getData("Text")` instead, so you might need to add checks to see which properties are supported by the browser.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering, i had lost all hope for this and implemented a custom editor using a contentEditable div (which accepts newline characters).  Let me try your answer out though and i'll get back to you with how it worked out for me.

Comment: Great. I've edited to add a fiddle where you can try it out. And I've changed the code so that it preserves content that was already in the box, and adds a separator after the last pasted item. That probably makes more sense in most use cases, but of course you can adapt it to suit your needs.

Comment: The fiddle you linked is exactly how i would expect it to work. tested it in chrome.  I'm not sure about any compatibility with older browsers but as far as I am concerned this is a correct answer.